# Word for getting something or getting praised for something you don't think you deserve

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been struggling to find the word for this. Irrespective of whether the person actually deserves it or not, important factor being he thinks he doesn't deserve something he got or got praised for.

Comment: Please try to use it in a sentence. Here are some guesses, but I am not sure if any are really capturing what you are getting at: Unworthy?
Unearned?
Unmerited?
Ignoble?

Comment: Or it could be *modest, humble, self-effacing*...

Answer (score 1):

That the speaker doesn't believe it can make them **excessively humble** or **overly modest**.

It's difficult to capture the emphasis on the *speaker's belief* in a word or two, but it should be obvious from the context.

It could simply be **undeserved praise** ([Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22undeserved+praise%22) 21,600 results). [First hit](https://odb.org/2014/10/21/undeserved-praise/):

> I accepted the praise even though I knew I didn’t deserve it. [...] am I guilty of accepting undeserved admiration.

Or **unwarranted**, **unjustified**, **unmerited**, **unworthy** (credit @InterstellarProbe). 
Or **inappropriate**, **disproportionate**, **excessive**. 
But this says nothing about whose perspective this opinion comes from (or whether it is accurate).

Answer (score 0):

It could be,
unanticipated, unforeseen, unlooked-for
to express that the one recieving has not expected it. but that misses the point of him not thinking himself worthy.
Maybe in the verb you could do like:
"He was **shocked by** the **unforeseen** praise!"